# How to start ASP.NET Core Web API site for testing using Selenium

Tags: selenium, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, ui-testing

I am trying to write Automated UI Tests for my ASP.NET Core Web Api solution using selenium.
The main question I have - is there any solution to to run my site for Selenium web driver?

When I debug test for home controller, site is not started, and Selenium web driver fails.

One solution I found - is to [run IIS Express in TestInitialize](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2011/12/22/asp-net-mvc-selenium-iisexpress), but maybe some more solutions exist?

P.S. Another solution just faced up - is to [run dotnet.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689247/starting-iis-express-before-running-selenium-tests-on-asp-net-5-mvc-6). Seems more clear for me.

Comment: I simply use `dotnet run` in a combination with `Process.Start()` at the beginning and at the end kill the process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134374/programmatically-start-a-net-core-web-app-for-selenium-testing

Answer (score 3):

`dotnet run` works well to get the application started, but when I test with Selenium, I like to have more control over some of the services (e.g. skip starting background services, [bypass authentication](https://geeklearning.io/how-to-deal-with-identity-when-testing-an-asp-net-core-application/), etc.).

Here is a class that I am using for this. I tried to stick close to the `WebApplicationFactory` pattern.

```cs
// tests/MyApp.Tests/SeleniumServerFactory.cs

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MyApp.Tests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Fixture class to start a server instance to do browser/UI tests.
    /// </summary>
    public class SeleniumServerFactory<TStartup> : IDisposable
        where TStartup : class
    {
        private readonly IHost _host;

        public Uri BaseAddress { get; }

        public SeleniumServerFactory()
        {
            IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    // Copied from Program.cs
                    // ...
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<TStartup>();

                    // Assumes your project is in src/MyApp.
                    // This can be updated based on your solution layout.
                    var relativePathToProject = Path.Join("src", "MyApp");
                    webBuilder.UseSolutionRelativeContentRoot(relativePathToProject);

                    // Use a dynamic port to prevent overlapping tests from breaking
                    webBuilder.UseUrls("http://127.0.0.1:0");
                });

            // Apply your configuration overrides below to the builder.
            ConfigureServices(builder);

            // Start the host in the background.
            // Shut it down in the Dispose method below.
            _host = builder.Build();
            _host.Start();

            // Store base address so that tests can pass it to the browser.
            BaseAddress = new Uri(_host.Services.GetRequiredService<IServer>().Features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>().Addresses.First());
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // Add your authentication overrides, etc. here ...
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _host.Dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

I then use this class as a fixture in my xUnit tests:

```cs
// tests/MyApp.Tests/Browser/SeleniumTests.cs

using System;

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using Xunit;

namespace MyApp.Tests
{
    public class SeleniumTests
        : IClassFixture<SeleniumServerFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly Uri _baseAddress;

        public SeleniumTests(SeleniumServerFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _baseAddress = factory.BaseAddress;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TitleShouldStartWithAppName()
        {
            using browser = new FirefoxDriver();
            browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(_baseAddress);
            Assert.StartsWith("MyApp - ", browser.Title);
        }
    }
}
```

(I based this loosely off of [Scott Hanselman's article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/real-browser-integration-testing-with-selenium-standalone-chrome-and-aspnet-core-21). However, this only covers ASP.NET Core 2.1 and some changes have been made to the `TestServer` class that make this no longer work in ASP.NET Core 3.0+, so I updated my example to work with ASP.NET Core 3.0+.)

There's probably some better abstraction that could be done, but this works for me so far. To dive deeper, cf.:

- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4892
- https://www.hanselman.com/blog/real-browser-integration-testing-with-selenium-standalone-chrome-and-aspnet-core-21
- https://www.meziantou.net/automated-ui-tests-an-asp-net-core-application-with-playwright-and-xunit.htm