# Programmatically start a .NET Core web app for Selenium testing

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core

I am currently trying to setup some UI tests on a Core web app, however I am not able to get the web app started. Using the command line directly with "dotnet run" from the web app directory works. The problem comes when I try to use Process to run it before executing my tests nothing happens.

```
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = "dotnet",
            Arguments = "run",
            WorkingDirectory = applicationPath
        }
    };
    process.Start();
```

Has anyone been confronted to a similar issue before and/or managed to solve it? I may be misusing `Process`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns that adding `UseShellExecute` to my StartInfo and setting it to `false` made it work:

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "dotnet",
        Arguments = "run",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WorkingDirectory = applicationPath
    }
};
process.Start();
```

The default for `UseShellExecute` is true but it would be similar to running `cmd dotnet run` instead of `dotnet run` which is what I needed.

Comment: after you started it, were you able to stop it?

Comment: nm. I got it to close using the following             if (_webprocess != null && _webprocess.HasExited == false)
            {
                _webprocess.CloseMainWindow();
                _webprocess.Close();
            }
calling Kill() wasn't working.

Comment: In my case it stops when the program ends

Comment: What if `dotnet` installed but not in PATH?

Comment: Upon installation, it should be in PATH. If you are working within a terminal or application that should use it you need to restart it so that it has the right PATH value. Then it should work. However, if it is not in PATH then you may either re-install or manually add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ProcessStartInfo Startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
Startinfo.FileName = "D:\\TFS\\QA\\SH_LoadTest\\SH_LoadTest\\bin\\Debug\\SH_LoadTest.exe";
StartInfo.Arguments = "Your Arguments";

Process pro = Process.Start(Startinfo);
```

Comment: You can actually use Autoit to start .net core application

Comment: It gives me the same result as before :/