# Start asp net core app from another assembly

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-core

Is that the only way to start an Asp netcore application from another assembly: [Programmatically start a .NET Core web app for Selenium testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134374/programmatically-start-a-net-core-web-app-for-selenium-testing) ?

I have my Asp Net Core app (imagine this is the initial template) and a test project. I want to start the server from the tests project and to be accessible over HTTP, execute some Selenium tests then stop the server.

I want to use something like:

```c#
var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartUp<MockStartUp>();
var host = builder.Build();
host.Run();
```

Using that approach the tests are not executed. And it hangs up.

Extending the WebApplicationFactory is not a solution since it uses `TestServer`.
Also I've checked [Integration test docs from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
and [Real browser testing by Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/RealBrowserIntegrationTestingWithSeleniumStandaloneChromeAndASPNETCore21.aspx)

any ideas ?

Comment: Why it's not a solution, because it uses TestServer? That's a full version of your app running in memory. Perfect for tests. Maybe specify why that doesn't work for you?

Comment: But the Selenium cannot access the app while it is in memory. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Are you running your tests using c#? Or some front-end library, like protractor?

Comment: I try to execute them from Visual Studio `Test Explorer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4892) of github/aspnetcore project and it helped me to solve my project. Now it can be integrated with azure pipelines.